# Spring Security does not throw Error when authorization header is not present after login with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I follow [Spring Security and Angular JS](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_the_login_page_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_ii) for HTTP Basic authentication, by adding Authorization header to $http headers:

```
const headers = {
    authorization: "Basic " + btoa(this.login + ":" + this.password)
};

this._$http.get("user",
    {
        headers: headers,
    })
    .then(
        this.showUser.bind(this),
        this.showError.bind(this)
    );
```

Inside `showUser` I redirect to `jobs` component with `$location`:

```
this._$location.path("jobs");
```

And inside `jobs` component, I load available jobs:

```
public $onInit() {
    this._$http.get("jobs").then(function(response) {
        this.jobs = response.data;
    }.bind(this));
    this.authenticated = this._loginService.isLogged();
}
```

**Intentionally** without authorization header, to prove everything work. I thought it should be abandon by `Spring Security` with `HTTP 401 Unauthorized` or something like that, but it worked without authorization header. When I logout from another browser window and reload jobs it's OK, jobs aren't loaded. But I think (and I hope) authorization data (HTTP Basic) should be present in every request. Here's my security config:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .formLogin()
        .successHandler(
            new DifferentRoleBasedStartingURLsAuthenticationSuccessHandler()
        )
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/logout")
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/jobs/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/interviews/**").authenticated()
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
    ;
```

Maybe here I made a mistake. I think rule `.antMatchers("/jobs/**").authenticated()` should make `jobs/` also authenticated. Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

---

**UPDATE 2016-07-31**:
Maybe authorization headers are not needed with every request in Spring with Angular? My repo is here: [Playground for Spring and Angular (AngularJS branch)](https://github.com/radek-anuszewski/hire-platform/tree/Angular_JS), password is `test` for every created user.

Comment: Why is there a form login when you're trying to use http basic authentication? Also note that form login in spring is cookie based so perhaps that's why you're not getting the results you're expecting. Your authorizeRequests() section is correct. The tutorial you're referencing also doesn't configure form login so i'm not sure why it's there.

Comment: @Pieter, if I remove it, will it work? Sorry that I am asking, I can not check it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Basic Authentication then it doesn't make much sense to also configure form login in spring. When using basic authentication, the http Authorization header needs to be present for each request that requires authentication on the server. If no authorization header is present for a protected resource, Spring returns a 401 response.

Your setup looks correct to me (and yes, "/jobs/**" matches "/jobs"), but I guess your experiment to verify if the security constraints are working failed because the server also sets a jsessionid cookie that can be used to authenticate you. So if you request a protected resoure without Authorization header but with a valid jsessionid cookie than the server can still authenticate you.

You can tell spring-security not to interact with the http session by setting the session creation policy to STATELESS.

Try the following security configuration:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/jobs/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/interviews/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and();
}
```

Comment: I reversed previous order of matchers (`ant....ant....anyRequest().permitAll()`), set `sessionCreationPolicy` to `SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER` (is that what you mean in code? You wrote `ALWAYS`) and it worked - thank you very much!

Comment: indeed, SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS in the sample code isn't what I wanted to  write :) I've updated the code snippet.

Comment: I've updated the example so that it uses SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS instead of SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER. With the NEVER policy spring still interacts with the http session if one exists. See http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.3.RELEASE/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/config/http/SessionCreationPolicy.html

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the order you have configured the security, Spring Security applies the rules in the order it is given which means you initially restricted the pattern then opened it up again with  `.anyRequest().permitAll()`. I have fixed the order in the below code.

```
http
    .formLogin()
    .successHandler(
        new DifferentRoleBasedStartingURLsAuthenticationSuccessHandler()
    )
    .and()
    .logout()
    .logoutUrl("/logout")
    .and()
    .httpBasic()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/jobs/**").authenticated()
    .antMatchers("/interviews/**").authenticated()
    .and()
    .csrf()
    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
;
```

Comment: I changed order to `anyRequest().permitAll().antMatchers("/jobs/**").authenticated().antMatchers("/interviews/**").authenticated()`, and I am confused - it still does not require HTTP Basic. All in all - maybe, with Spring Security and Angular, it does not need authorization data with every request, e.g  only with first and then Spring remembers them? I am definetely not an expert, but maybe `Cookie:JSESSIONID.....` and `X-XSRF-TOKEN` are enough? I am really confused in way how it works. My repo is here: [Playground for Spring and Angular](https://github.com/radek-anuszewski/hire-platform)

Comment: Correct branch: [Playground for Spring and Angular (AngularJS branch)](https://github.com/radek-anuszewski/hire-platform/tree/Angular_JS)

Comment: Built multiple Angular Spring Security and it works perfectly. I will have a look at your code and let you know.

Comment: This anwser is wrong. The request matchers are indeed considered in order but only the first matching request macher is used. So by specifying anyRequest() as the first request matcher none of the other matches will be used. This is clearly mentioned in the javadoc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeRequests--